# SharedPreferences getString NULL parameter

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Will I receive an error (Exception) on some devices if I set the second parameter of `SharedPreferences.getString`  NULL?

```
SharedPreferences settings = ...

String data = settings.getString(_.PREFIX , null);
```

Will it cause an exception or an error on at least one device? Or I have to wrap this part of code in try-catch block?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting. Please paste the logcat.

Comment: Try adding `settings.getString(_.PREFIX,"");`

Comment: I receive data = null. But I don't know will this work on all devices.

Comment: settings.getString(_.PREFIX,""); should  work. The second argument is just saying when the preference has no value "" will be returned, you can set any other string that you think is the default value can be set. All you have to do is whenever you are calling getstring check if the value is not not "" then perform the operations on the string, if its "" then the preference value was not saved and you might want to set the preference value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String data = settings.getString(_.PREFIX , null/*Null here is default value*/);
null - u can receive when your SraredPreferences have not this item(For example if u call/get this string before setting to this field any info or user clear cash of application from settings of device). I think it's can be normal situation, and u can remove "null" with some default value if you hope to got it(some emum field).
If u don't suppose get null validate  data before using. 
I thin'k your app must be ready get both variant, because user can change normal workflow.

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking if you *will* get an exception if you set the second parameter to null, the answer is no (at least not unless you reference the result without first checking it is not null). The second parameter in the `getString()` method is the default value (i.e. the value that will be returned if there is nothing found for your prefix. So, it is perfectly acceptable to set `null` as your default value, as long as you realize (and account for) the fact that the value returned by your `getString()` could be null.