# Null object reference after checking != null

Tags: java, android, string, null, sharedpreferences

I have weird problem with null checking. I'm using shared preferences where i have stored phonenumber.

`SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String number = settings.getString("number1", null);`

Before i use that String value i check if it's null

```
if(number != null){//trying to format number but it gives error: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference}
```

In my other app this works fine but in this project it gives me trouble.
I dont understand if it has something to do with Services because working app is using background service and this uses JobIntentService.

Can someone tell why this gives error?

Comment: Please post more of your code - i.e., the stacktrace showing your have a NullPointerException, the line it points to, and any lines necessary for context.

Comment: Either settings object itself is null or the key is wrong, thus you are getting null.  Check if "settings" is null and the shared prefs key you are using to store the phone number. is it "number1"?

Comment: If Your String is not null but contains only "" then You can get NPE when trying to parse number. Add !number.trim().equals("") to the null check

Comment: See the bellow links: - [SharedPreferences return null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31056106/9944300) - [SharedPreferences getString returns null ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25968768/9944300) - [sharedpreferences return null value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12489725/9944300)